# How to generate a 2D periodic pattern like below image from pseudorandom binary sequence?

Tags: image-processing, random

I want to generate a 2 dimensional periodic pattern from a pseudorandom binary sequence like this one with the following context:

A periodic pattern satisfies the equations (1) and (2)

W(x + q0N0, y) = W(x, y); q0, N0 >1 (1)

W(x, y + q1N1) = W(x, y); q1, N1 > 1, (2)

where N0 and N1 determine the periodicity of repetitions and q0 and q1 a repetition number on the horizontal and vertical directions. Generation from pseudorandom values {−1, 1} produces a rectangular, binary valued pattern.

[image: 2D periodic pattern]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be to take a small pseudo-random 2D pattern (the sequence) and repeat it periodically so that neighboring tiles are always mirrored giving a sense of smooth continuity.

After you specified your requirements with `W(x + q0N0, y) = W(x, y)` and `W(x, y + q1N1) = W(x, y);` it becomes clear, that this is exactly (without the mirroring part) what you want.

You simply have to repeat a random pattern a certain number of times in both directions.

Example (similar to your image where the period length in the vertical direction is longer than in the horizontal direction)

[image]

Code (in Matlab)

```
% base pattern
N0 = 20;
N1 = 5;
base = rand([N0, N1]) > 0.5; % pseudo-random

% periodically repeating the pattern
Q0 = 5;
Q1 = 20;
pattern = zeros([N0*Q0,N1*Q1]);
for q0 = 1 : Q0
    for q1 = 1 : Q1
        pattern((q0-1)*N0+1:q0*N0, (q1-1)*N1+1:q1*N1) = base;
    end
end

% save
imwrite(pattern, 'test.jpg');

% display
imagesc(pattern);
axis image;
colormap(gray);
```

The first lines just compute a random, binary pattern of a certain size N0 x N1

```
% base pattern
N0 = 20;
N1 = 5;
base = rand([N0, N1]) > 0.5; % pseudo-random
```

Then comes the definition of the number of repetitions of the pattern in each direction

```
Q0 = 5;
Q1 = 20;
```

Finally, in two nested but rather simple for loops, the base pattern is repeated

```
pattern = zeros([N0*Q0,N1*Q1]);
for q0 = 1 : Q0
    for q1 = 1 : Q1
        pattern((q0-1)*N0+1:q0*N0, (q1-1)*N1+1:q1*N1) = base;
    end
end
```

The computation of the indices (where to place the base patterns) fulfills your requirement equations

```
(q0-1)*N0+1:q0*N0, (q1-1)*N1+1:q1*N1
```

---

Old Example (with mirroring)

[image]

Code (in Matlab)

```
% base pattern
N = 20;
base = rand(N) > 0.5; % pseudo-random

% multiplying the pattern
M = 4;
pattern = zeros(N*M);
for i = 1 : M
    for j = 1 : M
        b = base;
        % mirroring the base
        if mod(i, 2) == 1
            flip(b, 2);
        end
        if mod(j, 2) == 1
            flip(b, 1);
        end
        pattern((i-1)*N+1:i*N, (j-1)*N+1:j*N) = b;
    end
end

% save
imwrite(pattern, 'test.jpg');

% display
imagesc(pattern);
axis image;
colormap(gray);
```

The patterns are flipped (mirrored) in one or two direction sometimes to simulates some kind of smoothness (symmetry) of the pattern.

Comment: @RahulSavsani The specification in your comment should be part of the question here. Could you include it in the question using the edit button below the question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the question so you can go through this.

Comment: @RahulSavsani Thanks, I will look at it later later, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Just guide me through the context that I've uploaded in the question. So I can move forward. Thank you. And can I find any video or material about the code that you uploaded as I am new to MATLAB?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped a lot.

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686865/how-to-rotate-a-2d-periodic-pattern-generated-from-pseudorandom-binary-sequence) @Trilarion Please have a look at this question and answer if you can.